# Newly promoted to 8th grade. Graduated 7th grade. Describing my education, am I a "7-grader" or "8-grader"?

Tags: vocabulary

I just completed grade 7 successfully. Newly promoted to grade 8. I'm literally an 8th grader now.

But if I were to describe my level of education, wouldn't I be a "7th grade graduate"? Because I've no knowledge of grade 8 until classes start. I've "graduated" grade 7 which therefore is the limit of my knowledge.

When I post questions on MSE (the Maths site), I'm often in a fix. At times, I've had to add notes like:

> Please answer bearing in mind that I'm a X grader (with the knowledge of grade X). So my knowledge on topic Y is extremely limited.

"7th grader" seems more reasonable to say in this case (for reasons already mentioned above). "8th grader" seems fit for instances like:

> We're **8th graders** now — the oldest kids in middle school. Maria, isn't it wonderful!

(Note: I'm NOT from the US.)

#### I'm confused. What should I actually say if I've to describe my level of knowledge (as in the MSE example)?

Comment: I think it is unlikely that actual grade levels is really helpful, since the knowledge imparted will vary from place to place. As far as general education is concerned, saying you completed elementary school, junior high school (middle school), high school, vocational (community) college, bachelors degree, etc. should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonly used term I've been hearing recently for a student who is between years of schooling is "rising ______th grader". So you would describe yourself as  a "rising eighth grader".

You could also avoid this by saying

> Please note that I have just completed seventh grade, so answers should be comprehensible to someone at that level.

If you're celebrating completing seventh grade, you can certainly call yourself an eighth grader.

Comment: Just the kind of answer I wanted! You understand me so well. +1 Accepted this.

Comment: I haven't heard "rising Nth-grader" myself, and I'm not sure I'd be able to interpret it, but perhaps it's more common outside Canada (where we don't say "8th-grader" anyway).

Comment: @LukeSawczak It's certainly a newer usage. I don't know when it first started being used in the US but it's been at least 10 years, becoming more common recently. Here's a [Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070614193059AA6qPpC) question from 2007.

Comment: @Catija Personal knowledge bank officially updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would say **"I am *in* the 8th grade."**

However it's an odd thing to be especially proud of, since going from 7th to 8th grade is fairly routine.  In the US at least, the 8th grade is often the upper class of a three-year *junior* high school, and it isn't until you graduate *high school*, five years later, that the level of education really matters.

Of course individual families might give their children praise for moving from one grade to another, and there's nothing really wrong with this.  But it wouldn't ordinarily be considered a noteworthy achievement.

Additionally, the challenge with saying what level of math you know is that, in the US, the actual *classes* you take vary from school to school and student to student, so it's difficult to judge exactly what a 8th grade student should be learning.  It's better to state **what kinds of math you know well**, rather than just relying on your age and grade in school.

Comment: +1 for remarking that the exact grade is less important to note than one's level.

Answer (score 2):

To give a Canadian perspective, here we don't say that one "is an Nth-grader" but that one "is in grade N". This syntax makes it simple to express your relationship to your grade at any time.

> I finished grade 7 last week. Now I'm going into grade 8. (*or* I'm going into grade 8 in the fall.) Late next year I'll be in grade 9.

Even if other countries *do* use terms like "7th-grader", that doesn't exclude paraphrases like the above. I think anyone would find them both easy to understand and fairly natural-sounding.